# How to test if a Float or Double is infinite or NaN?

Tags: scala, floating-point, double

In Java there is an API to test [if a number is infinite](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#isInfinite()) or [NaN](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#isNaN()).

I cannot find anything like this in Scala, and to call the Java functions it seems I need to box the value or to call java.lang.Double static method:

```
Double.box(x).isNaN

java.lang.Double.isNaN(x)
```

Is there really nothing more "native" to Scala to test for infiniteness / NaN-ness?

Comment: I have created an issue for IntelliJ Scala plugin regarding missing completion on Float expressions: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-8954

Answer (score 16, accepted):

These are methods on the boxed `scala.Double`. No need to manually box them.

```
scala> 1.2.isNaN
res1: Boolean = false

scala> 1.2.isInfinity
res2: Boolean = false

scala> (0.0 / 0.0).isNaN
res8: Boolean = true

scala> (1.0 / 0.0).isInfinity
res5: Boolean = true
```

Comment: I feel silly now. I did not find them because IntelliJ autocomplete does not offer them, but they really compile just fine.

Comment: scaladoc / REPL 1, IntelliJ 0.